# DOMDocument grouping nodes, where the bug? How to debug a 'Not Found Error' of LibXML2?

Tags: php, domdocument, libxml2

**How to debug a  'Not Found Error' of LibXML2?**
The function (simplifyed/rewrited for post here) groups a list of nodes by a tag.

```
  function groupList(DOMNodeList &$list,$tag,&$dom) {
        $list = iterator_to_array($list); // to save itens
        $T = $dom->createElement($tag);
        $N = count($list);
        if ($N && $list[0]->nodeType==1) {
              for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) 
                    $T->appendChild( $list[$i] );
                   // here print $dom->saveXML($lista[0]) shows the expected XML.
              $list[0]->parentNode->replaceChild($T, $list[0]);
    //Fatal error:  ... 'DOMException' with message 'Hierarchy Request Error'
    // also error with $dom->documentElement->replaceChild( $T, $list[0] );  
    // where error is: ... 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'
              for($i=1; $i<$N; $i++)
                    $list[$i]->parentNode->removeChild($list[$i]);
        }//if
        return $N;
  }//func
```

---

Edit1: with `$list[0]->parentNode->replaceChild($T, $list[0]);` the error is  'Hierarchy Request Error'.  A debug `print $dom->saveXML($list[0])` shows the expected XML.

---

Edit2: **illustrating  by INPUT and OUTPUT**,

INPUT

```
  <root><b>10</b><a/><a>1</a><b>20</b><a>2</a></root>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT of `groupList($dom->getElementsByTagName('a'),'G')`

```
  <root><b>10</b>
     <G><a/><a>1</a><a>2</a></G>
  <b>20</b></root>
```

Comment: The error means that `$list[0]` is not a direct child of `$dom->documentElement`, so it cannot find the child node to replace.

Comment: Hum, thanks... But, as I commented, `$list[$i]->parentNode->replaceChild` have same error (!). The value of `$lista[0]->nodeType` is 1, and $dom->saveXML($lista[0]) shows the expected XML.

Comment: If you show an example snippet of XML and how you are invoking this function, along with the expected output, you would get better responses.

Comment: @nickb thanks (ok!), I edited with an I/O example.

Answer (score 0):

Was a bug (?)... Solution: to use the same algorithm, we need to clone or IMPORT the nodes,

```
  function groupList(DOMNodeList &$list,$tag,&$dom) {
        $list = iterator_to_array($list); // to save itens
        $d2 = new DOMDocument;
        $T = $d2->createElement($tag);
        $N = count($list);
        if ($N && $list[0]->nodeType==1) {
              for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) 
                  $T->appendChild( $d2->importNode($list[$i], true) );
              $dom->documentElement->replaceChild(
                    $dom->importNode($T, true),   $list[0]
              );
              for($i=1; $i<$N; $i++)
                    $list[$i]->parentNode->removeChild($list[$i]);
        }//if
        return $N;
  }//func
```

---

But, I don't understand why (!), a basic algorithm, without iterator_to_array, works (!) ... Well, near to work fine (error on returned $dom),

```
 function groupList2(DOMNodeList &$list,$tag,&$dom) {
       $n = $list->length;
       if ($n && $list->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
          $T = $dom->createElement($tag);
              for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) 
                 $T->appendChild( clone $list->item($i) );
              $dom->documentElement->replaceChild( $T,$list->item(0) );
              for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
             if ($i) $list->item($i)->parentNode->removeChild($list->item($i));
        }//if
        return $n;
  }//func
```

returns

```
  <root><b>10</b><G><a/><a>2</a></G><b>20</b><a>2</a></root>
```